# How write a file using StreamWriter in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm having trouble when creating a `StreamWriter` object in windows-8, usually I just create an instance just passing a string as a parameter, but in Windows 8 I get an error that indicates that it should recieve a Stream, but I noticed that Stream is an abstract class, Does anybody knows how will be the code to write an xml file?, BTW I'm using .xml because I want to save the serialized object, or does anyone knows how to save to a file a serialized object in Windows 8?.

Any ideas?

Currently using Windows 8 Consumer Preview

Code:

`StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("person.xml");`

Error:

`The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.StreamWriter.StreamWriter(System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: This has nothing to do with Windows 8 or any OS. You just need to pass the correct parameter to the constructor. When it says it needs a `Stream` you have to use a class that extends `Stream`. I would suggest that you *google* about `Stream`. The first result I got even shows a video of how to use it (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKGjWMlba9s)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but in fact I know how to use the StreamWriter class, but in this case I created a Windows Metro Style project and I'm working with XAML, and the StreamWriter class it does not work as it used to work in Windows Form apps, I just get this error, and even that I tried what you proposed (create a class that extends the Stream class), it just implements empty methods and does not have a method that receive as a parameter the path where the stream will be created...

Comment: ..., all that I found in google, just display the way I know about how to create a StreamWriter object, I couldn't find any reference that indicates how to create a StreamWriter or Stream in a Windows Metro project. Does anybody work with Streams in a Windows Metro Project, how will be the code for write a file using StreamWriter?

Comment: This is one of the fundamental changes in WinRT.  You can't just write a file anywhere you want anymore, you have to use isolated storage.  And you need to use asynchronous I/O with the await keyword.  Can't find a good example and not close to a Win8 machine right now.

Comment: thanks Hans, I think that is the answer I was expecting, could you please provide me a link where I can find more information about you just answered. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Instead of StreamWriter you would use something like this:

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync();

using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    using (IOutputStream outputStream = fileStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
    {
        using (DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream))
        {
            //TODO: Replace "Bytes" with the type you want to write.
            dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            dataWriter.DetachStream();
        }

        await outputStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

You can look at the [StringIOExtensions](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/12598#235918) class in the [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) library for sample use.

EDIT*

While all the above should work - they were written before the [`FileIO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.aspx) class became available in WinRT, which simplifies most of the common scenarios that the above solution solves since you can now just call [`await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, contents)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.writetextasync.aspx) to write text into file and there are also similar methods to read, write or append strings, bytes, lists of strings or `IBuffers`.

Comment: Thanks for the updated suggestion to use `FileIO`, works for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a common static method which you can use through out application like this

```
 private async Task<T> ReadXml<T>(StorageFile xmldata)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<myclass>));
        T data;
        using (var strm = await xmldata.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            TextReader Reader = new StreamReader(strm);
            data = (T)xmlser.Deserialize(Reader);
        }
        return data;
    }

    private async Task writeXml<T>(T Data, StorageFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlSerializer xmlser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            xmlser.Serialize(sw, Data);

            using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (IOutputStream outputStream = fileStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                {
                    using (DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream))
                    {
                        dataWriter.WriteString(sw.ToString());
                        await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                        dataWriter.DetachStream();
                    }

                    await outputStream.FlushAsync();
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(e.Message.ToString());

        }

    }
```

to write xml simply use

```
 StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("data.xml",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await  writeXml(Data,file);
```

and to read xml use

```
  StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("data.xml");
      Data =  await  ReadXml<List<myclass>>(file);
```