# Why StreamWriter can't get string in it's constructor?

Tags: c#, streamwriter, .net, microsoft-metro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How write a file using StreamWriter in Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290820/how-write-a-file-using-streamwriter-in-windows-8)

I'm developing a Metro App and I want to serialize my data to an XML file. when I want to create a new `StreamWriter`, It doesn't get an string data as address and it just get stream. I closed and reopened VS but I couldn't see any change.

Comment: I get the feeling that the API is altered for security purposes.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: then how can I access the files?!?

Comment: Maybe you should read up on the storage options available for Metro.