# WinRT: how to save WriteableBitmap to localfolder

Tags: windows-runtime, writeablebitmap

How to save a WriteableBitmap to localfolder using C# in WinRT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check WinRT XAML Toolkit for a set of extension methods to do exactly what you need: http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0657c67a93d5#WinRTXamlToolkit%2fImaging%2fWriteableBitmapSaveExtensions.cs

Answer (score 0):

Here are bits and pieces of the answer

```
var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width,height);
var stream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
```

than you can get `IOutputStream` from `Stream` to write the data into the local folder.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream) post explains how to convert `Stream` to `byte[]`

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290820/how-write-a-file-using-streamwriter-in-windows-8) explains how to write `byte[]` array to localfolder.

Comment: That would lead to writing pixel data directly to a file though. Wouldn't you rather compress it to a well known format?