# Save XML document Windows RT development

Tags: c#, windows-rt

So far manipulating XML (reading/writing) has been a bit more challenging than standard windows.  I am trying to open the config file for editing, make changes and then save the file again to disk.

I can open the file as a `StorageFile`, convert it to `XDocument` but I am having trouble saving the `XDocument` to disk, can anyone offer code that would do the trick?  Currently I have

```
             StorageFile file = await installedLocation.GetFileAsync(fileNameAndPath);
            var data = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            string actualXML = data.ToString();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(actualXML);
            // do work
            //save
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
            doc.WriteTo(w);
```

Comment: take a look at this `MDSN` documentation for Windows App Store http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx

Comment: thanks, I took a look at that prior, some good info there.

Comment: Still can't get the save to work.  The problem is XDocument.Save takes a stream, does that mean that the changes get written to a stream and then I have to save the stream to disk?

Comment: look at this stackoverflow link try changing your code to utilize this code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290820/how-write-a-file-using-streamwriter-in-windows-8

Answer (score 1):

If it is throwing Access denied to path, check or try to give permission in your app manifest to respective folders.