# Stream to File in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

How i can save a Stream to File in WinRT. Currently i am working on a Open Source library for creating PDF file in windows 8. I build the stream with pdf content, now my requirement is to save this stream to file. Can anyone please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290820/how-write-a-file-using-streamwriter-in-windows-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're working with C#? One way to do it would be to read the stream content using DataReader and store it into a byte[] buffer. After that you can create the file like this:

```
var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("filename", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, buffer);
```

Then again, if you already have to byte data for the pdf, you can skip making it a stream in the first place.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Same question but with an emphasis on 'streams'.  I want to serialize some data that I write to a user file.  When the user starts up the application, the state of the data model is read from this file.  How do I connect these isolated storage objects to the library of stream functions?